# How can I find pseudo element using Playwright?

Tags: python, playwright, playwright-python

In my webpage I have some pseudo elements.

For example:

[image]

How can I find the ::after element using Playwright?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't get the pseudo-element because the browser doesn't expose it. But you can get the CSS properties using JavaScript.

```
const someCSSPropertyValue = await page.locator('<selector>').first()
  .evaluate(el =>  window.getComputedStyle(el, ':after').someCSSProperty);
```

I bet that will be helpful if you need to test that some `:after` was applied.

Comment: Thanks , it was helpful for me in one of my scenarios.